# DeepLearning4J Doc2Vec input structure

Tags: java, deep-learning, deeplearning4j, dl4j

As I see less than 500 questions related on deeplearning4J here and most years old, first a different question: is DL4J dead? Do I really have to deal with horrible, horrible Python just to build my AI? I don't want to!

Now real question, I feel a bit stupid but really documentation and googling is a bit lacking (see question above): I have been reading up the past days on building a simple document classifier with DL4J which seems straight forward enough, although the follow-up material again is frighteningly sparse.

I build a `ParagraphVector`, add some labels, pass in the training data and train. I also figured out, the data is passed in as a `LabelAwareIterator`. Using a file structure I even found this [documentation](https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/org/deeplearning4j/text/documentiterator/FileLabelAwareIterator.html) by DL4J how to structure the data. But what if I want to read the data from say an API or similar and not through file structuring? I am guessing I need a [LabelAwareDocumentIterator](https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/org/deeplearning4j/text/documentiterator/LabelAwareDocumentIterator.html), but how is data supposed to be structured and how to feed it in? I read about structuring as a table of text and label as columns but that seems rather sketchy and very imprecise.

Help would be much appreciated, as are better resources than what I have found so far. Thanks!

--UPDATE

Through reading of the source code (usually a good idea to just check the implementation) it looks like what I really want is the `SimpleLabelAwareIterator`. That code is nicely readable. Dont really understand what the `LabelAwareDocumentIterator` is for yet. Anyway the Simple one just needs a List of `LabelledDocuments`. The `LabelledDocuments` just have a string content and a list of labels. So far so good will try implementation this evening. If it works out, I will post this as an answer.

Comment: > is DL4J dead?

No, it isn't. Stackoverflow's Q/A format isn't great for this type of questions, as there is a lot of back and forth to tease out the specific problem that people have and actually help them with it. 

The forums at https://community.konduit.ai are a better place for that.

Comment: thanks a lot, I am really glad to hear that and will head right over there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach in the update worked out. I am now using a SimpleLabelAwareIterator that I fill with a list of LabelledDocuments. Short code sample:

```
    ArrayList<LabelledDocument> labelledDocumentList = new ArrayList<LabelledDocument>();

    for(Document input : documents){
      LabelledDocument doc = new LabelledDocument();
      doc.setContent(input.content);
      doc.addLabel(input.label);
      labelledDocumentList.add(doc);
    }
    
    SimpleLabelAwareIterator iter = new simpleLabelAwareIterator(labelledDocumentList);
    
    TokenizerFactory t = new UimaTokenizerFactory();
    ParagraphVectors vec = new ParagraphVectors.Builder()
                        .minWordFrequency(1)
                        .labels(Arrays.asList("A", "B"))
                        .layerSize(100)
                        .stopWords(new ArrayList<String>())
                        .windowSize(5).iterate(iter).tokenizerFactory(t).build();
    
    vec.fit();
    tools.saveObject(vec, "models/modelName");
```